# Partial declarations of 'Triangle.MainWindow' must not specify different base classes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, shapes

I've been facing an error that tells me that the partial declarations must not specify a different base class.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Shape
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Stretch = System.Windows.Media.Stretch.Fill;
            this.StrokeLineJoin = PenLineJoin.Round;
        }
```

I get error from :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Shape
```

The 'MainWindow' gives me error about the specifying of a different base. How do i go about rectifying this error?

My XAML currently, is the default one:

```
   <Window x:Class="Triangle.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I have yet to edot anything from the XAML as this codes are codes i found somewhere from online and is using it to try out whether or not it work.

Answer (score 1):

`MainWindow` normally extends `Window`.

So in your code-behind you'll see `public partial class MainWindow : Window`, and in your associated XAML you'll see something like:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        ... />
    ...
</Window>
```

To extend another class (not sure what `Shape` is, but I'm assuming it's appropriate in this case), you'll have to correct your XAML in addition to the code-behind... something like this:

```
<Shape x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       ... />
    ...
</Shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

`MainWindow : Shape`? I suppose it to be  `MainWindow : Window`

do please verify the base class (root element) from the designer of the `MainWindow.xaml` and use the same base class here.

typically top level window classes like default `MainWindow` class derives from `Window`. whereas in your case I can see it is being derived from `Shape`

if you are trying to create a shape class then there is no `InitializeComponent()` in shape class and it does not need a designer hence a partial class is not required. last but not the least the class name `MainWindow` does not sounds a nice name for the same. you may perhaps revise it.

Answer (score 0):

your main page should be in the format

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
```

inheriting only Page Class.